# How to Tail -f output with colors using only Awk and show the rest of the output?

Tags: awk, tail, logs

I was able to do a `tail -f` output with colors using the `awk` command. But I'm unsure how to output the rest of the log as it seems to be filtering only those 2 lines. I also want to see the other lines as the log is written.

What do I need to put in the `awk` command to show the rest of the output?

Image of my issue. The red text above is without using `awk` and displays the entire `tail -f log`. And below that is the same command with the `awk` color filtering.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of printing matching lines with decorations, decorate matching lines, and print everything:

```
awk '/User@Host:/ { $0 = "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m" }; /Query_time:/ { $0 = "\033[29m" $0 "\033[39m" }; 1'
```

This `awk` program consists of three patterns and associated actions:

- lines matching `User@Host:` are processed with `$0 = "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m"`, which surrounds the current line with the given escape codes;
- lines matching `Query_time:` are processed with `$0 = "\033[29m" $0 "\033[39m"`;
- lines for which the pattern `1` is non-zero (so all lines) are processed with the default action, which is to print the current line.

These are cumulative: all actions whose patterns match the current line are executed, in the order in which they are defined. A line matching `User@Host:` is modified (first action) and printed (third action). A line matching `Query_time:` is modified (second action) and printed (third action). A line matching neither is printed (third action).

That's the simplest technique to print all lines, without having to keep track of whether a line has been processed yet (to avoid printing a line twice). Instead of printing something in every set of action statements, we modify the current line as appropriate, and only print it once (but always print it).

Comment: What is the $0 variable for and how is that used? And what does the 1 at the end of the line represent? thanks

Comment: But how come you're able to print the entire section while I can only print the line i searched for?

Comment: @duckx I've updated my answer to explain how it works. My approach here is to print all lines, modifying those which need colouring before they're printed.