# How can I use Awk to convert a unix timestamp to human readable when doing a Tail -f logfile?

Tags: awk, timestamps, tail, logs

I'm currently doing a `tail -f mysql.log` and also have it [color coded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283964/how-to-tail-f-output-with-colors-using-only-awk-and-show-the-rest-of-the-output/283966). But how would I use awk to convert the unix timestamps to human readable format?

```
tail -f /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log | awk '/User@Host:/ { $0 = "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m" } /Query_time:/ { $0 = "\033[36m" $0 "\033[39m" } 1'
```

[image]

Comment: Please use text instead of images and format your post properly. Also, what's your `awk` flavor ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU awk (`gawk`), which is usually the case on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin, then you can use the [`strftime`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#index-strftime_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029) function.

```
if (match($0, /^(.*timestamp=)([0-9]+)(.*)$/, parts)) {
    time = strftime("%F %T", parts[2]);
    $0 = parts[1] time parts[3];
}
```

On an embedded system with BusyBox, you may have a more restricted version of awk but a `date` utility that's capable of doing the conversion.

```
if (match($0, /timestamp=[0-9]+/)) {
    system("date +'%F %T' -d " substr($0, RSTART+10, RLENGTH-10)) | getline time;
    $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART) time substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH);
}
```

With only POSIX tools, there's no way to convert between human-readable dates and Unix timestamps other than doing the calculation by yourself. (I know there's shell and awk code available on the web for that, but I don't have a link handy.) I recommend making sure you have something better installed, such as gawk, perl, python, etc.

Comment: `gawk match` has groups so you can simplify a bit with `match($0, /timestamp=([0-9]+)/, a) { ... strftime("fmt", a[1]) ...  }` -- although for this specific case I think @aphorise FS trick is cleverer, in the sense of 'clever' that isn't unmixedly good.

Answer (score 0):

Discarding colours - you may use:

```
# | piped at the end 
awk -F'SET timestamp=' 'NF > 1{ system("date -d @" $2) }'
```

Stripping the colours out in-line with the reset makes it more challenging; I suspect that you can control / adjust that by removing the end included escape sequences that relate to the *timestamp* portion.

Comment: i dont get it. do i pipe that into awk?